# disk was full but wordpress still having issues

Tags: updates

When trying to update wordpress from 3.1 to 3.1.1 I am getting the error

```
Incompatible Archive.: PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
```

Some searching shows a cause of this can be that the servers disk is full. My disk is not full but it was about a week ago. I believe Wordpress has the disk still flagged as full and not writeable. Does that sound plausible or does any one have any other suggestions?

I have three Wordpress blogs on the server and this is only affecting one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the upgrade download corrupted (probably because of disk space) - just do the upgrade manually.

Comment: Thanks, manual upgrade worked just fine. I had not done that before but it was easy.

Comment: Solved this finally... even after the manual upgrade I could no longer do automatic upgrades and found some other wordpress features failed. The site was on a Plesk server, I used the control panel to configure PHP as an apache module. I was then able to upgrade worpress. I then changd back to fast CGI and everything worked perfectly.